# c# winform , How to get only available Computer accounts

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have `account` table with some accounts. Some of them are already assigned to a computer. Some of them are not - they are available.

Here is my class:

```
public class ComputerAccount
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public int DepId { get; set; } 
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
}
```

and my computer class:

```
public class Computer
    {
        public int ComputerId { get; set; }
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }
        public int DepId { get; set; } 
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
    }
```

If, in the Account table, `ComputerId == null`, then I know this account is available.

I have a computer list in my DataGridView. When I want to update, I just CellClick to load another Update form.

I have `Loadaccounts` funtion in update form that displays all accounts in ComboBox.

What I want in ComboBox is to populate only those available accounts,  plus current account, if the computer has an account. Otherwise only those which are available.

I can populate all computer ids where `ComputerId == null`, but this should include the current account. It does not display the current account. As previously mentioned, if the computer has an account I want to display it, plus the computer ids where `ComputerId == null`.

Here is what I am trying:

```
using (db)
{

   var account = (from u in db.ComputerAccounts
                  where u.DepId == DepId  && u.ComputerId == null
                  select new { Name = u.AccountName, Value = u.AccountId }).ToList();

                    account.Insert(0, new { Name = "Choose account", Value = -1 });

                    CmbAccounts.DisplayMember = "Name";
                    CmbAccounts.ValueMember = "Value";
                    CmbAccounts.DataSource = account;
                }
```

But this does not populate current account because I'm using `u.ComputerId == null`. I have this because some Accounts do not have any computer bound. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you just need to add another `account.Insert()` specifically for the "current account if the computer have account" case?

Comment: What is the _current account_? How do you know what the "current account" is? How do you determine the `ComputerId` or `ComputerName` of the current account? Once you either one of these, you should be able to add it to your query. Something similar to `&& (u.ComputerId == null || u.ComputerName == "myComputerName")`

Comment: @user9938 Thank you for your response. Let say I have som computers list in a datagridview, som of them the yhave already account but not all. Let say I want to edit one of the list computers tha thave acount. I have Cell_click event on datagridview. When I click then I have edit form for displaying in detali about just that computer and I want to change accountname for that computer. All accounts are populatin in Combobox. I want to display all avialable accounts plus the current acount for that computer.